# How to implement Exception Handling in Parsing?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, logging, error-handling

I'm creating a parsing application, which parses ~20 sites, ~7-15 values from each. Pseudocode looks like:

```
ParserA : ParserBase 
{
public override SomeEntity Parse(...)
{
 SomeEntity se = new SomeEntity();

 //some code, parsing value1;
 //some code, parsing value1;
 //some code, parsing value1;

 //some code, parsing value2;
 //some code, parsing value2;
 //some code, parsing value2;

 //some code, parsing value3;
 //some code, parsing value3;
 //some code, parsing value3;

 //some code, parsing value4;
 //some code, parsing value4;
 //some code, parsing value4;

 ...

 return se; 
}
}

ParserB : ParserBase {...} 
ParserC : ParserBase {...} 
...
```

etc.

As soon as parsers have never done well with html(layouts happen 
to change during time), I need to implement exceptionHandling and 
logging. I need to parse as much as possible, and errors must be logged. I know 2 ways to deal with it:

```
public override SomeEntity Parse(...)
{
 SomeEntity se = new SomeEntity();

try {
 //some code, parsing value1;
 //some code, parsing value1;
 //some code, parsing value1;

 //some code, parsing value2;
 //some code, parsing value2;
 //some code, parsing value2;

 //some code, parsing value3;
 //some code, parsing value3;
 //some code, parsing value3;

 //some code, parsing value4;
 //some code, parsing value4;
 //some code, parsing value4;

 ...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
 //Log
}
 return se; 
}
```

Pros: Easy to implement

Cons: if i get exc at value5, i have no chance to parse value6,7,.. etc.

2)

```
ParserA : ParserBase 
{
public override SomeEntity Parse(...)
{
try
{
 //some code, parsing value1;
 //some code, parsing value1;
 //some code, parsing value1;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 // Log
}

try
{
 //some code, parsing value2;
 //some code, parsing value2;
 //some code, parsing value2;
catch(Exception e)
{
 // Log
}

try
{
 //some code, parsing value3;
 //some code, parsing value3;
 //some code, parsing value3;
catch(Exception e)
{
 // Log
}

try
{
 //some code, parsing value4;
 //some code, parsing value4;
 //some code, parsing value4;
catch(Exception e)
{
 // Log
}

 ...

}
}
```

Pros: Everything, that can be parsed, is parsed;

Cons: Too much copypaste (remember 20 parsers, 7-15 values in each.

I want to write less, do more, so i've implemented Safecall function which takes delegate and executes it inside a try-catch block, and logs ot. So now i have to write this:

```
SafeCall( () => { 
 //some code, parsing value4;
 //some code, parsing value4;
 //some code, parsing value4;
});
```

instead of this:

```
try
{
 //some code, parsing value4;
 //some code, parsing value4;
 //some code, parsing value4;
catch(Exception e)
{
 // Log
}
```

Is this a good solution or i'm reinventing a square wheel?

Comment: what is the code to parse single values? It feels that there will be commonalities between different values and I would stick the error handling and logging in there.

Comment: @Grzenio, parsing logic for values is DIFFRENT.

Comment: It seems like your parsing methods are doing too much.  If it's important that each part have error handling, why wouldn't you split the logic out into more granular methods that contain their own exception handling / logging?

Comment: Could you wrap up that parsing logic into classes which implement the same interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with the SafeCall option as it works, is easy to read and you can always change the SafeCall implementation if you want to change the logging mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

I would say defensive coding in XP terms would be 'the' solution in your case .

- That is checking for **UIElement != null** before parsing any values from the expeceted UI element. Because the user is tend to change the HTML markup. (I have experienced this in my screen scraping application)
- This way you don't have to use multiple try catch blocks to parse different values.
- You can simply load the **DOM** and traverse along the interested node(UIElement) and parse only the non - null elements .

Please refer the [Best practices for Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts(VS.71).aspx) from Microsoft.

I take that you just want to skip the nodes, that were not found, from parsing.

Hope this helps,

Thanks,

Vijay

Comment: Yes, i want to skip the nodes that cant be parsed(sort of). 
I do  not want to use null checks because usually i have to check this : XpathQuery Result, Regex Result, Collection Length, and sometimes - all of them together.